# Correct syntax for bash script as userdata for AWS runinstance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am trying to launch a new ec2 instance through lambda everytime a particular event occurs. I have a bash script that I want to run everytime that a new ec2 instance launches and I would like for it to be attached using the userdata parameter for  runinstances.

I have tested the script and it works well when i launch the instance through the aws console.

I suspect that it is probably because my syntax is wrong. I realise that the question is very basic but I have tried various permutations multiple times and am unable to get it up and running.

```
   function(next) {
        console.log("INITIALIZING EC2");

        var params = {
        ImageId: 'ami-b2c934d2',
        InstanceType: 't2.micro', //'c4.4xlarge',
        MinCount: 1, MaxCount: 1,
        KeyName: 'malpem2102'
        UserData : console.log(new Buffer('#!/bin/bash \n
            sudo apt-get install awscli -y \n
            echo alarm \n
            aws configure set default.region us-west-2 \n
            aws configure set aws_access_key_id AKIAIXXXXXXXXX \n
            aws configure set aws_secret_access_key U2fyRtyakG1kAXXXXXXXXXX \n
            instance=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id/` \n
            aws cloudwatch put-metric-alarm --alarm-name $instance --alarm-description 
            "Terminate the instance when it is idle for 10mins" --namespace "AWS/EC2" 
            --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=$instance --statistic Average  
            --metric-name CPUUtilization --comparison-operator LessThanThreshold 
            --threshold 5 --period 120 --evaluation-periods 5 --alarm-actions 
            arn:aws:automate:us-west-2:ec2:terminate \n').toString('base64'));
        };
```

Comment: Donot post aws_access_key_id  and aws_secret_access_key in forum.

Comment: Check for logs **/var/log/cloud-init.log** inside the ec2 instance to get to know more on the exact reason.

Comment: console.log returns undefined, hence your userdata is undefined

Comment: have you found any solution to this?  I'm stuck with the same issue

Answer (score 1):

When using API calls you need to send your commands as a base64-encoded text string.

So, you need to get the raw commands data and encode it to base64 for entering into the `UserData` param.

For example, if you have the following commands:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash -
sudo yum install -y nodejs
sudo yum install -y git
git clone https://github.com/user/repo
cd repo
npm i
npm run start
```

After you encode to base64 with a tool like the [Base64 Decode and Encode](https://www.base64encode.org/), you can use as param your UseData like this:

```
const params = {
    ImageId: 'ami-b2c934d2',
    InstanceType: 't2.micro', //'c4.4xlarge',
    MinCount: 1, MaxCount: 1,
    KeyName: 'malpem2102',
    UserData: 'IyEvYmluL2Jhc2gNCmN1cmwgLS1zaWxlbnQgLS1sb2NhdGlvbiBodHRwczovL3JwbS5ub2Rlc291cmNlLmNvbS9zZXR1cF8xMC54IHwgc3VkbyBiYXNoIC0NCnN1ZG8geXVtIGluc3RhbGwgLXkgbm9kZWpzDQpzdWRvIHl1bSBpbnN0YWxsIC15IGdpdA0KZ2l0IGNsb25lIGh0dHBzOi8vZ2l0aHViLmNvbS9jb2RlcmFkZS9hd3MtZWMyLWV4YW1wbGVzDQpjZCBoYmZsDQpucG0gaQ0KbnBtIHJ1biBzdGFydA=='
};
```

You can also encode using a native Javascript approach with the following code:

```
let commandsString = `#!/bin/bash
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash -
sudo yum install -y nodejs
sudo yum install -y git
git clone https://github.com/user/repo
cd repo
npm i
npm run start`;

UserData: new Buffer(commandsString).toString('base64');
```

For further information, read the documentation of [Running Commands on Your Linux Instance at Launch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html).

Answer (score -1):

i think that you just need to remove console.log instruction from your code.